# Importing information from the LinkedIn account to Careers 2.0

Tags: support, jobs, linkedin

According to the FAQ,

> I already entered my experience and education on LinkedIn.
>
> Great! You can import it from LinkedIn with just three clicks.

Unfortunately, it doesn't say *which* 3 clicks, and I wasn't able to find them.

Comment: I don't have an "import LinkedIn" link or button there.

Comment: It is no longer possible: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312851/feature-request-import-cv-from-linkedin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your sidebar look like this?

[image: Sidebar With LinkedIn]

If you are not an active candidate, you may not see the link to edit your profile, which is the only page that shows the LinkedIn import link.  If you are a passive candidate or you have no profile at all on Careers, you will need to obtain an invite in order to create a profile and import your LinkedIn information.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the problem is that I am a passive candidate.