# Make clear that an invite is needed to become an active candidate

Tags: discussion, jobs

The FAQ says that an invitation is needed to get a profile at all. I have got a profile without an invitation (presumably "based on your participation on Stack Overflow"), so I assumed no further invitation was needed. However, according to [Importing information from the LinkedIn account to Careers 2.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80759/importing-information-from-the-linkedin-account-to-careers-2-0/80773#80773), it is required to become an active candidate.

I think it should be made clear in the FAQ, or even better, the "Edit profile" button should be visible but disabled, with a tooltip explaining that an invite is required.